# Как добавить переменную ACF в JS (Vue) код?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, acf

Есть несколько полей, созданных в ACF, которые нужно добавить в данный JS код. Как это можно реализовать? Пробовал ACF JS API (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/javascript-api/)), но не заводится.

```
function Top10() {
    return [
        {
            name: "<?php echo the_field('name'); ?>",
            artist: "...",
            cover: "https://site.com/img/1.jpg",
            source: "https://site.com/mp3/1.mp3",
            url: "https://www.youtube.com/",
            favorited: false
        },
        {
            name: "<?php echo the_field('name'); ?>",
            artist: "...",
            cover: "https://site.com/img/1.jpg",
            source: "https://site.com/mp3/1.mp3",
            url: "https://www.youtube.com/",
            favorited: false
        },
        {
            name: "<?php echo the_field('name'); ?>",
            artist: "...",
            cover: "https://site.com/img/1.jpg",
            source: "https://site.com/mp3/1.mp3",
            url: "https://www.youtube.com/",
            favorited: false
        }
    ];
}
```

На странице вызывается так:

```
<player :tracks="top10" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        new Vue({
            el: '#Playlist_Top10',
            data: function() {
                return {
                    top10: Top10()
                };
            },
            template: '<player-app :top10="top10"/>',
            components: {
                'player-app': PlayerAppComponent_Top10(PlayerComponent()),
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Во первых echo get_field('name'), а во вторых что бы сработало так нужно что бы функция Top10 была обьявлена в html коде, а не в js файле

Comment: @fortavey Спасибо огромное, все заработало! Всегда выводил значение поля через the_field('var'). Но да, в моем примере ошибка - echo тогда не нужен

Comment: Тогда поставьте галочку возле ответа, что бы закрыть вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых echo get_field('name'), а во вторых что бы сработало так нужно что бы функция Top10 была обьявлена в html коде, а не в js файле